# Incorrect syntax near '.'. Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a SQL query Join with Function it gives me error this error:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Tbl a
  CROSS APPLY V_TBL_STR(a.Number)
```

What can be the error?
Thanks

Comment: V_TBL_STR is Table-Valued Function or Scalar Function? Did u check that function individually - SELECT dbo.V_TBL_STR('some text here')  ?

Comment: if i use like this SELECT dbo.V_TBL_STR('some text here')  not problem

Comment: [CROSS APPLY on Scalar Function](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/97336/6381) from DBA may help.

Comment: i tried but still not working, Table-Valued Function cant join table ?

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database set to?

Comment: @Martin Smith Level 100

Comment: Post a full MVCE that repros the issue. No repro http://rextester.com/MTUN4747

Comment: @Adinugraha - I have removed you table value function & put simple table. see my example

Answer (score 1):

Please try & let me know.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 Tbl AS a
 CROSS APPLY dbo.V_TBL_STR(a.Number) AS V
```

**This is sample**. I only have removed your function & put static value to check. It works for you then modify your sql or may be something problem with your sql

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Tbl
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'A' AS ABC UNION SELECT 'B' AS ABC) AS A
```

Comment: same error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Tbl a
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT V_TBL_STR(a.Number))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use below query :

SELECT * FROM Tbl AS a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [DBO].[V_TBL_STR](a.Number) [Number]) AS T
```

Comment: @Adinugraha,I posted answer for your query.Try above answer.

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find either column "DBO" or the user-defined function or aggregate "DBO.V_TBL_STR", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: First check is it scalar function or not and post your last tried query here.

Comment: its Table-valued Functions, `SELECT * FROM COMP_AGENT_STRUCT_HIST_LEVEL AS a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROm [DBO].V_AGENT_STR(a.AGENT_NO) AGENT_NO) AS T ` thats my query

Comment: Try this : SELECT * FROM COMP_AGENT_STRUCT_HIST_LEVEL AS A 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM [DBO].[V_AGENT_STR](A.AGENT_NO)) AS T

Comment: still same error **Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.**